# Randomize elements within objects within arrays for javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I want to create a short fun project where I can randomize the "answers" function, and I can choose to display the "riddle" element of that randomized object. Is there a way to do that?

```
var answers = {

  reflection:{answer:"reflection", riddle:"You saw me where I could not be. Yet, often you see me. What am I?", level:"medium"},
  rainbow:{answer:"rainbow", riddle:"I am beautiful, up in the sky. I am magical, yet I cannot fly. To people I bring luck, to some people, riches. The boy at my end does whatever he wishes. What am I?", level:"easy"},
  comet: {answer:"comet", riddle:"What zips through the sky with a tail of fire and dust. It could be an omen, its origin to discuss?", level:"easy"},
  spine: {answer:"spine", riddle:"This is needed both for courage and hardcover books.", level:"medium"},
  eyes: {answer:"eyes", riddle:"We are two brothers on opposite sides of the road, but we never see each other. Who are we?", level:"medium"},
  sting: {answer:"sting", riddle:"If you're stealing honey, be prepared to receive vengeance in this form", level:"easy"},
  push: {answer:"push", riddle:"It can be done to buttons and shopping carts. What is it?", level:"easy"},
  wine: {answer:"wine", riddle:"The older this thing grows the more valued it becomes. It is always much better when its breathing is done.", level:"medium"},
  laundry: {answer:"laundry", riddle:"When it's dirty this should never be aired in public.", level:"easy"},
  pillow: {answer:"pillow", riddle:"I lose my head in the morning and regain back it at night. What am I?", level:"medium"},
  tennis: {answer:"tennis", riddle:"A sport with love and service played by singles and pairs.", level:"easy"},
  bell: {answer:"bell", riddle:"It is able to speak because it has a hard gone. You know what it is as soon as it has sung. What is it?", level:"medium"},
  wheelbarrow: {answer:"wheelbarrow", riddle:"I have two legs, but they only touch the ground while I'm at rest. What am I?", level:"Hard"},
};

// Randomize the riddles

var random = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
// document.getElementById('riddle').innerHTML = random;

console.log(random);
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: `.length` is for arrays. `answers` is an object, not an array.

Comment: sorry for the mess, I was testing to see how I can post the code and have a gray background behind it. First time posting on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

`answers` is an object, but the code you're using is for selecting a random element of an array.

You can get an array of all the object property names using `Object.keys()`, then select a random element of that.

```js
var answers = {

  reflection:{answer:"reflection", riddle:"You saw me where I could not be. Yet, often you see me. What am I?", level:"medium"},
  rainbow:{answer:"rainbow", riddle:"I am beautiful, up in the sky. I am magical, yet I cannot fly. To people I bring luck, to some people, riches. The boy at my end does whatever he wishes. What am I?", level:"easy"},
  comet: {answer:"comet", riddle:"What zips through the sky with a tail of fire and dust. It could be an omen, its origin to discuss?", level:"easy"},
  spine: {answer:"spine", riddle:"This is needed both for courage and hardcover books.", level:"medium"},
  eyes: {answer:"eyes", riddle:"We are two brothers on opposite sides of the road, but we never see each other. Who are we?", level:"medium"},
  sting: {answer:"sting", riddle:"If you're stealing honey, be prepared to receive vengeance in this form", level:"easy"},
  push: {answer:"push", riddle:"It can be done to buttons and shopping carts. What is it?", level:"easy"},
  wine: {answer:"wine", riddle:"The older this thing grows the more valued it becomes. It is always much better when its breathing is done.", level:"medium"},
  laundry: {answer:"laundry", riddle:"When it's dirty this should never be aired in public.", level:"easy"},
  pillow: {answer:"pillow", riddle:"I lose my head in the morning and regain back it at night. What am I?", level:"medium"},
  tennis: {answer:"tennis", riddle:"A sport with love and service played by singles and pairs.", level:"easy"},
  bell: {answer:"bell", riddle:"It is able to speak because it has a hard gone. You know what it is as soon as it has sung. What is it?", level:"medium"},
  wheelbarrow: {answer:"wheelbarrow", riddle:"I have two legs, but they only touch the ground while I'm at rest. What am I?", level:"Hard"},
};

var keys = Object.keys(answers);
var randomKey = keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)];
var random = answers[randomKey];

console.log(random);
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius! You probably think this is so easy, but to me who has just started to learn what Javascript is, this is a great breakthrough for me. Thank you.